# Software to crop the image based on the click/coordinates

Tags: images

I have bunch of photos of different items. I would like to crop them and found a lot of tools that crops the images in bulk. It's good, however when I was taking pictures not all of the items were in the middle of the picture. So now when I crop all the pictures by the same settings then not all of them appearing in the middle.

My question: is there any software where I can do something like that?

- Click on the place where I think the real middle of the picture is supposed to be
- It crops the picture by predefined settings using the middle point from previous step (let's say 100px from left 200px from top)

In that case I would have the pictures with the same size and centered item.

Any other solutions/suggestions are also welcome

Thanks

Comment: Sure you want that in pixel sizes? Similar to the fact that the item is not always in the center, the item usually also does not have the same size. What I typically want is a specific aspect ratio like 4:3 or 16:9 first (with arbitrary resolution) and then scale it down to a defined size like 800*600px.

Comment: Just a suggestion (but I can't figure out to comment in app)
It would be trivial to make in php, to show the image in a browser. On click the browser sends the coordinates to server. Php contains functions to manipulate images.

Comment: @Thomas: items are more or less the same size

Comment: @Lenne: yes, I can write software by myself, but I thought there is solution already